# Android : set visibility of individual buttons in a custom ListView

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, android

I have a ListView with a custom Adapter (extending BaseAdapter), and the layout of each row consists of a TextView and a Button. After the list is created, I want to change the visibility of specific buttons.

For this, I would need to programatically access the View of an individual row. I am not able to find out how to do it. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099979/android-identify-individual-items-in-row-of-listview) mentions getView(int position), but I can't find that method; `getView()` needs 3 parameters. What do I pass as `convertView` to `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`?

Could you please point me in right direction?

UPDATE: The View obtained by `View v = myListView.getChildAt(myListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());` is null. Also, myListView.getChildCount() is returning 0.

Answer (score 1):

`onItemClick` will pass you the View in the ListView that was clicked. Then you can grab that View and do whatever you want with it, including changing visibility, etc.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, clicks on the ListView rows are not going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I of a custom adapter I used in a list view in which the user can select items in the listView and mark them for Delete. The key is to add the onClickListener after you have a view. Then you can use that to not only change the view, but update the data of the adapter too.
Hopefully you can modify this code to suit your particulars.

```
private class DeletePlayerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Player> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<Player> data;

    public DeletePlayerAdapter(Context context, int layout,
            ArrayList<Player> list) {
        super(context, layout, list);
        this.layoutResourceId = layout;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        PlayerHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context)
                    .getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new PlayerHolder();
            holder.player_name = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.player_name);
            holder.player_number = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.player_number);
            holder.seeded_button = (ImageButton) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.delete_toggle);
            holder.player_name.setTypeface(tf);
            holder.player_number.setTypeface(tf);
            row.setTag(holder);
            players_array.get(position).marked_for_delete = false;

        } else {
            Log.d("PLAYER_ADAPTER", "NOT_NULL ROW");
            holder = (PlayerHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        holder.seeded_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            private int pos = position;

            public void onClick(View v) {
                ImageButton b = (ImageButton) v;
                if (b.isSelected()) {
                    b.setSelected(false);
                    players_array.get(pos).marked_for_delete = false;
                } else {
                    b.setSelected(true);
                    players_array.get(pos).marked_for_delete = true;
                }
            }
        });
        Player p = data.get(position);
        holder.player_name.setText(p.name);
        holder.player_number.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));
        holder.seeded_button
                .setSelected(players_array.get(position).marked_for_delete);
        return row;
    }

}

static class PlayerHolder {
    TextView player_number;
    TextView player_name;
    ImageButton seeded_button;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How do you call getView for a non-null row? I have onClickListeners for Buttons too; but I need to make the buttons visible based on time - there aren't going to be any clicks.

Comment: ListView recycles views in order to work efficiently. So you will get a non-null row if that view has already been inflated. Likely you will need to use Adapter.notifyDatSetChanged() to force ListView to update the views. Then list view will call getView() for each visible row.